# Reverse for 'ratio' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, jquery, json, django, pandas

Caught an exception while trying to render:

```py
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'ratio' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboards/ratio']
```

Here is the views.py:

```py
def ratio(request, ticker1, ticker2):
  tickers_values = TSDB.objects.filter(TICKER__in = [ticker1, ticker2]).values("DATE", "TICKER", "CLOSE")
  tickers_list = []
  for ticker in tickers_values:
    tickers_list.append([ticker['DATE'], ticker['TICKER'], ticker['CLOSE']])
  df = pd.DataFrame(tickers_list, columns = ['DATE', 'TICKER', 'CLOSE'])
  df = df.pivot_table(values = 'CLOSE', index = 'DATE', columns = 'TICKER')
  print(df)
  json_list = []
  df['RATIO'] = df[ticker1]/df[ticker2]
  for i in df[['RATIO']].itertuples():
    json_list.append([totimestamp(i[0])*1000, i[1]])
  return JsonResponse(json_list, safe = False)
```

I don't have the slightest clue of where this error is coming from. I'm going to assume that it is what I am passing in `$.getJSON()`. (I am new to django and I am trying to create a data plot using Highcharts.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS:

```
var tkr_data = { ticker1: "ticker1", ticker2: "ticker2" };
qs = $.param(tkr_data);
$.getJSON("{% url 'dashboards:api_tkr_ratio'}" + "?" + qs,
...
```

`urls.py`

```
path('api/tkr_ratio', views.api_tkr_ratio, name = 'api_tkr_ratio'),
```

`views.py`:

```
def api_tkr_ratio(request):
    ticker1 = request.GET.get('ticker1', 'N/A')
    ticker2 = request.GET.get('ticker2', 'N/A')
    ...
```